# Is there are infinitely many nonnegative integers that not of the following four forms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The four forms are:

$3x^2 + (6y-4)x - y$

$3x^2 + (6y-2)x + y - 1$

$3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1$

$3x^2 + (6y-3)x - y\ $,$\ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

For example: $4=3*1^2+(6*1-4)*1-1\ $ , is the min number of the four forms,
then $\ 0, \ 1. \ 2.\ 3\ $  must not of the four forms, how to prove that the set of these numbers are infinite?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164893/are-there-infinitely-many-nonnegative-integers-not-of-the-following-four-forms.